# CodeIgniter .htaccess index.php rewrite not working on sub directory level

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am developing a new website by using codeigniter and yesterday I hosted it on a new server. It's working perfectly with home page(`landing page URL: http://(domain-name)/(folder-name)`). But, if I try to access any other page, it shows:

> 404 Not Found error "The requested URL /(folder-name)/ Register was not found on this server."

```
URL: http://(domain-name)/(folder-name)/Register
```

I am using `routes.php` so,

Register =

```
$route['Register'] = 'register/index';
```

I already changed  `index.php` to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and changed

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and my `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ folder-name/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks and Regards

Comment: which version of CI are you using?

Comment: my CI version is  2.2.0

Comment: Starting version 3.X, Codeigniter strictly checks for filenames. All the class names (controller and model) and pertaining files should be strictly named in Ucfirst! Make sure you have done that. You won't get such errors in mac, because the file system is case insesitive but linux throws up! Try changing file names according to the strict conventions

Answer (score 1):

Try below lines by clearing your .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It worked for me. Hope so will solve your problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the htaccess file using the following link

http://addictors.in/remove-index-php-from-url-in-codeigniter/